# Several errors concerning lstlisting

Tags: listings

In my Bachelor Thesis I'm using highlighted code using `lstlisting`, which comes with the listingspackage.

Unfortunately I'm getting some errors and I cannot figure out why they appear. Especially because the output is as expected. Highlighting, caption and refering are working fine in the resulted pdf.

Here is my minimum working example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[super, comma, numbers, square, sort]{natbib}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{color}  
\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{caption}
\definecolor{sh_comment}{rgb}{0.12, 0.38, 0.18 } %adjusted, in Eclipse: {0.25, 0.42, 0.30 } = #3F6A4D
\definecolor{sh_keyword}{rgb}{0.37, 0.08, 0.25}  % #5F1441
\definecolor{sh_string}{rgb}{0.06, 0.10, 0.98} % #101AF9
\newcommand{\lstJava}[1]{\lstinline[language=Java,breaklines=true,basicstyle= \listingsfontinline]$#1$}

\begin{document}

% define some fancy Code formatting according to the Java Eclipse formatting
\lstset {
    frame=single,
    rulesepcolor=\color{black},
    showspaces=false,showtabs=false,tabsize=2,
    numberstyle=\tiny,numbers=left,
    basicstyle= \listingsfont,
    stringstyle=\color{sh_string},
    keywordstyle = \color{sh_keyword}\bfseries,
    commentstyle=\color{sh_comment}\itshape,
    captionpos=b,
    xleftmargin= -2.0cm, xrightmargin=0.5cm,
    lineskip=-0.3em,
    escapebegin={\lstsmallmath}, escapeend={\lstsmallmathend},
    linewidth=1.25\textwidth
}

\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
    \captionsetup{width=1.25\textwidth}
    \lstdefinelanguage{XML}
    { % adjust the formatting for XML files
      morestring=[b]",
      morestring=[s]{>}{<},
      morecomment=[s]{<?}{?>},
      stringstyle=\color{sh_string},
      identifierstyle=\color{sh_comment},
      keywordstyle=\color{sh_keyword},
      morekeywords={xmlns,version,type, servlet, display, name, xsi, web, app, class, init, param, value, schemaLocation, load, on, startup, mapping, url, pattern, id} % list custom attributes
    }
    % Here the 1st and 2nd error will appear (line 47)
    \begin{lstlisting}[language=XML, caption={xml: Definition of available GET Methods for Java}, label={Jersey}]

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:
"foo"
</web-app>
    \end{lstlisting}
\end{minipage}

Refering Listing \ref{Jersey} on Page \pageref{Jersey}. \\

Refering Listing \ref{lst:Jersey_Hello_java} on Page \pageref{lst:Jersey_Hello_java}. 

\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
    \captionsetup{width=1.25\textwidth}
    % here the 3rd error will appear (line 63)
    \begin{lstlisting}[language=Java, caption={Hello.java: Definition der verfügbaren GET Methoden der REST-Schnittstelle mit Jersey für Java}, label={lst:Jersey_Hello_java}]
System.out.println("Hello World");
    \end{lstlisting}
\end{minipage}

Refering Listing \ref{lst:Jersey_Test_java}. Refering \ref{lst:Jersey_Test_Ausgabe} on page \pageref{lst:Jersey_Test_Ausgabe}.

\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
    \captionsetup{width=1.25\textwidth}
    % here the 4th error will appear (line 73)
    \begin{lstlisting}[language=Java, caption={Test.java: Implementierung eines einfachen Jersey Klienten zum Abfragen der Ressource über Volltext, XML und HTML.}, label={lst:Jersey_Test_java}]
System.out.println("Hello World");
    \end{lstlisting}
\end{minipage}

\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
    \captionsetup{width=1.25\textwidth}
    % here the last error will appear (line 81)
    \begin{lstlisting}[language=Java, caption={Konsolen-Ausgabe bei Ausführung von Test.java.}, label={lst:Jersey_Test_Ausgabe}]
Hello World
<?xml version="1.0"?><hello> Hello World</hello>
<html><title>Hello World</title><body><h1>Hello World</h1></body></html>
    \end{lstlisting}
\end{minipage}

\end{document}
```

When compiling (if that matters: I'm using the editor sublime text) LaTeX will throw the errors:

```
There were errors in your LaTeX source

./test.tex:47: Package Listings Error: Illegal type `s'. [...ble GET Methods for Java}, label={Jersey}]]
./test.tex:47: Undefined control sequence. [...ble GET Methods for Java}, label={Jersey}]]
./test.tex:63: Undefined control sequence. [...für Java}, label={lst:Jersey_Hello_java}]]
./test.tex:73: Undefined control sequence. [... und HTML.}, label={lst:Jersey_Test_java}]]
./test.tex:81: Undefined control sequence. [...t.java.}, label={lst:Jersey_Test_Ausgabe}]]
```

Comment: I don't get any errors with your code when I define `\def\listingsfont{\ttfamily}`

Comment: Also `\listingsfontinline` should be defined.

Comment: Thank you for your fast answers. Using cgnieders definition I got rid of the `Undefined control sequence` error. Unfortunately the `Package Listings Error` won't disappear. I also tried egreg's advice and included: `\def\listingsfontinline{\ttfamily}`. I guess the using of `listingsfontinline` is wrong. But I'm quite new to LateX and I dind't find suitable documentation about `listingsfontinline`

Comment: @Markus is your TeX distribution up to date?

Comment: `latex --version` sais:

`pdfTeX using libpoppler 3.141592-1.40.3-2.2 (Web2C 7.5.6)
kpathsea version 3.5.6
Copyright 2007 Peter Breitenlohner (eTeX)/Han The Thanh (pdfTeX).
Kpathsea is copyright 2007 Karl Berry and Olaf Weber.
There is NO warranty.  Redistribution (...)
Compiled with libpng 1.2.46; using libpng 1.2.49
Compiled with zlib 1.2.3; using zlib 1.2.3
Compiled with libpoppler`

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, I can confirm, no errors with `\def\listingsfont{\ttfamily}`, compiled with pdfLaTeX on MiKTeX 2.9, Editor: TeXworks.

Second, have you tried a very basic example? And then adding formatting for syntax highlighting?

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{listings}

\lstset{language=Java,
    basicstyle=\ttfamily,
    showspaces=true,
    numbers=left,
}
\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting}[frame=single]
    System.out.println("Hello World");
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! With your example above I do not get any errors, too. This helped me to identify the line which causes the error. When defining the highlighting for XML it comes to the line: `morestring=[s]{>}{<},` As soon as I remove this line I do not get any errors. I'm new to latex and the above code isn't from me and I don't know what this line is responsible for. But when I remove this line, my highlighting still works fine. Therefore the solution for me is to just keep it out. Thank you for your help!